# How do I get a horizontal rule below the table that spans the full text width?

Tags: tables, rules

I want a horizontal rule below the table which spans the full text width. I have tried the following approach, however, the rule only spans the table width and not the text width.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\newcommand*\tabendline{%
    \arrayrulecolor{mygray}\specialrule{1.15\heavyrulewidth}{0.15 cm}{0 cm}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \caption{\label{tab:table}Caption}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
            \hline
            A  & B & C & D  \\
            \hline
            a & b  & c & d \\
            e & f & g & h \\
            \tabendline
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: There's no need for the second instance of `\extracolsep{\fill}`. `\begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc @{}}` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add line out of tabular.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\newcommand*\tabendline{%
    \arrayrulecolor{mygray}\specialrule{1.15\heavyrulewidth}{0.15 cm}{0 cm}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \caption{\label{tab:table}Caption}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
            \hline
            A  & B & C & D  \\
            \hline
            a & b  & c & d \\
            e & f & g & h \\
            % \tabendline
        \end{tabular*}
        \color{mygray}\rule{\textwidth}{1.15\heavyrulewidth}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want a horizontal rule below the table which spans the full text width

I suggest you define `\tabendline` on the basis of `\hrule`, a curious little vertical-mode command that draws a horizontal rule whose natural width is whatever the width of the current vertical-mode group is -- often, but not always, `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\heavyrulewidth' length parameter
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for '\textcolor' macro
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcommand\tabendline{%
    \textcolor{mygray}{\hrule height 1.15\heavyrulewidth}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \caption{\label{tab:table}Caption\strut}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            cccc @{}}
            \toprule
            A & B & C & D \\
            \midrule
            a & b & c & d \\
            e & f & g & h \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}  
    \smallskip
    \tabendline 
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```